# flutter with AndroidView native player change orientation show black screen for a while

Tags: flutter, native, orientation, android-view

I'm coding with Android native player, and I want to change orientation with OrientationBuilder, when I change it to landDirection, I get a black native view.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([landDirection]);
```

As I know, the reason is widget rebuild each time I change orientation, so is there a better way to do this, or some others useful suggestions? Thx.